# Scripting Bridge and Apple Mail

Tags: xcode, cocoa, email, scripting, apple-mail

I'm am getting ready to attempt to implement Scripting Bridge for the first time, specifically to allow my program to construct and send emails to individual (or all) members of an opt-in email database.

Unfortunately, I'm already stuck on the first step... creating the Mail.h file.

According to Apple's documentation:

> To create a header file, you need to run two command-line tools—sdef and sdp—together, with the output from one piped to the other. This is the recommended syntax:
>
> sdef /path/to/application.app | sdp -fh --basename applicationName

However, when I attempt to execute this, I receive the following errors:

> -bash: sdef: command not found
>
> -bash: sdp: command not found

My guess is that I'm trying to execute programs that are (clearly) not installed on my system, which is a MacBook Pro running Lion (10.7.4)

A quick google search turned up an older version of sdef for v10.4, but I'm now wondering:  Is this process still the recommended procedure, or is there another way I should be generating a Mail.h header file?  Apple's documentation is rather vague on this point.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some additional research and experimentation, I was able to get everything working by allowing XCODE to create the header files, rather than doing it manually from the command line.

XCODE also uses the sdp and sdef commands, but had no problem accessing them. I am still not entirely certain why I could not run the commands in the bash shell, but I suspect they must be run from the root user perhaps?

In any event, here is a link to the Apple Documentation which outlines the steps I took to get everything working correctly:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SBSystemPrefs/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use sdef and sdp after installing the command line tools. These are an optional install since XCode 4.3.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW2